# How to remove a product catalog page ‘col-left sidebar’ and Product Detail Page ‘col-left sidebar’

Tags: layout

**Catalog page**

[image: Currently]

[image: objective]

**Product view page**

[image: Currently]

[image: objective]

My web:luoshi.biz THX!

Comment: You images are missing.

Comment: Sorry, but the picture in http://www.luoshi.biz/media/Edit1.png

Comment: Please change it in qst then.

Comment: I am trying...thank!

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1 - Recommended (Thanks to Rajeev)

You can change this by setting it in `local.xml`.

Create a file in `template_path/layout/local.xml` and add following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
      <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
   </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
       <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

## Option 2

Open your `template_path/layout/catalog.xml` file and find `<reference name="root">` section.

Here you will see your template type.

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        ....................
</reference>
```

You will need to change `<action>` part as:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

This change needs to be in following nodes:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label"> //for layered navigation
<catalog_product_view translate="label"> //for product view page
```

**Things to know**

Here we are telling magento to use our `1 column` template for catalog and product view page. All template types are located in `template/page/` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: editing core layout file such as  `catalog.xml` treating as a bad practice. You should recommend `local.xml` file or `theme.xml` file for such operations

Comment: Thanks @RajeevKTomy for suggestion, however I believe if you are creating a theme for magento in that case we are allowed to change in `catalog.xml` directly, right? So, if I have custom theme in place, I can change it directly.

Comment: You are right and wrong at the same time. :) . Suppose the theme providers provide you an upgrade in future (to overcome some security vulnerabilities or any other reason) and you really need the upgraded version, in that case, all the edit that you have done directly on that theme file will loose. So always use a `local.xml` file if possible. otherwise make the custom theme as parent theme and do your edit on a child theme (after setting a new theme location via admin)

Comment: Hmmm... make sense, thank you again. I guess I was crowded with thinking only about my own custom built theme.

Comment: Your answer is great. no doubt in it. But I can see that, a recommendation of direct edit is visible in your answers (some of your prev answers for sure). That is why I put this as a comment. To correct you and thus you will give us wonderful answers in future :) Kudos

Answer (score 1):

Some time layout is set from **admin panel..**

```
To change the product page layout:

From the Admin menu, select Catalog > Manage Products.
```

Find the product in the list, and click to open the record.

In the Product Information panel on the left, select Design. Then in the Design section, set Page Layout to a different column configuration.

When complete, click the Save button.

```
To change the category page layout:

From the Admin menu, select Catalog > Manage Categories.
```

In the Categories tree, select the category level you want to change.

On the Custom Design tab, set Page Layout to “1 column.”

Click the Save Category button.